# Can we authenticate application user with on-premise directory services with AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, saml-2.0

Am looking for authentication methods with our on-premise directory other than AWS Cognito user pool. I saw Lambda can be integrated with Azure AD. Our directory is SAML integrated. Can i achieve this with AWS Lambda function.? And how can i get access tokens to authorize API Gateway after authentication. If Possible, Please let me know how to achieve. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can use Azure AD as a openid or saml provider for Cognito. We do such thing in current project and so far so good. 
Additional option is adding authorization via AWS API gateway integrated with your lambda

Comment: We are already using on-premise GD and Cognito option is declined because client doesnt want user identity to be stored in user pool.

Comment: In this case try this thing https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html - in lambda may be your custom logic which may process data from tokens. policies returned by it may configure access to your defined endpoints in GW. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/call-api-with-api-gateway-lambda-authorization.html